# UbuntuでHHKBをBluetooth接続で使う方法がわかりません

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntuで今までRealForce（US）を使っていました．
HHKB（US）に乗り換えたのでBluetooth接続でHHKBを使用しようと思ったのですが，この２つはキーボードマッピングが異なるので新たに設定する必要があります．

以下のサイトを参考にして設定したのですが，USB接続されているRealForceのキーボードマッピングが変更されている？のか，HHKBは期待した通りに動作しません．

[HHKB をUbuntuで使う](https://jun-networks.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/11/20/160003)

おそらくこのUSB接続のRealForceが原因で全然うまく行かないと思い，試しに抜いてから設定しようとしたところ`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`でTUIが起動せず，そもそも設定できません。
以上から，「UbuntuでHHKBを使うときはUSB接続（Hybridなので可能）する」しかないのでしょうか？
それとも，キーボードマッピングの設定のときだけUSB接続で設定すれば，設定完了後はBluetoothで使えるようになるのでしょうか？

---

**追記**

`$ cat /etc/default/keyboard`の実行結果を以下に示します．
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
このようにHHKBのキーボード設定にしてあるはずなのですが，「キーボードレイアウトを表示」で表示されるレイアウトは以下のようになります（RealForceのレイアウトです）．
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
そのため，HHKBに様々な問題が発生しています．
一番致命的なのはCtrlがCapsLockになることです．
私はMacでCtrl+Spaceで切り替えを行っているので，これに合わせたい願望があり，現在の状況は致命的です．
もしこの質問でも私の意図がよくわからなかったら，申し訳ありませんが再度ご指摘頂ますようお願いいたします．

Comment: 「HHKB がまったく動かない」なのか、「BT接続で認識はするけど、キーマッピングが意図した通りに動かない」なのかがやや分かりづらい印象です。

Comment: 失礼いたしました．
私の質問方法が不十分でしたので追記させていただきました．
もしよろしければご享受いただけると幸いです．

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました．
以下に必要な手順をまとめておきます．

まず，私の場合は設定時にはtype-cでUSB接続する必要がありました．
設定が完了すればBT接続でも全く問題ありません．
普通に使用できます．

さらに，私はMacのキーボードレイアウトと同じようにHHKBが認識されるのを期待して「HHKB for Mac」のレイアウトにしていました．
これでは全くうまく行きません．
「HHKB」に修正する必要があります．
これで一度ログアウトすれば無事にHHKBのレイアウトになりました．

そして最後に今までcapslockをctrlに置き換えて使用していたので，そこを修正する必要がありました．
これをしないとCtrlが消滅します．．．

以上でubuntuでもHHKBが問題なく使用できるようになりました！
助言を与えてくださった皆様，本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0):

リンク先のやり方とは違うやり方を提案します
リンク先の`Ubutu キーボード設定`も`fcitxとmozc設定`も必要ありません。

`HHKB Hybrid Type-s`をBTで使っていて、`Ubuntu(18.04|20.04), mac`で使ってます。
質問者さんがやりたいのは日本語切り替えのバインドですかね？（と予測して書きます）
キーボードレイアウトの設定は割愛します

#### 1. DIP設定

```
2,3,5,6をON
```

#### 2. 入力メソッドの設定

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 3. Fcitx設定

自分は左右Altで切り替えられるように設定してます

[image: fcitx]

もしCtrl+Spaceで切り替えられるようにしたいのならば、下記を設定してみてください
こちらで動作確認したところ問題なく切り替えられました

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上で切り替えられるはずなので、Mozcの設定は不要です

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます．
そういうことではないです，申し訳ありません．
私の質問方法が不十分かつ，キーボードマッピングの問題ではなく，レイアウトの問題でした．
質問の方に詳細を追記しましたので，もしよろしければ確認していただけないでしょうか？